# C++ Cast sub-sub class to base

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance

With the classes below:

```
enum class OBJECT_TYPE {TYPE_1, TYPE_2, TYPE_3};

class BaseClass {
public:
    BaseClass();
    virtual ~BaseClass();
    OBJECT_TYPE getObjectType() { return m_objectType; }
protected:
    OBJECT_TYPE m_objectType;
}

class ChildClass : public BaseClass {
public:
    ChildClass();
    virtual ~ChildClass();
    virtual void init() = 0;
protected:
    // some other variables
}

class ChildChildClass : public ChildClass {
public:
    ChildChildClass ();
    ~ChildChildClass ();
    void init() override { m_objectType = OBJECT_TYPE::TYPE_3 }
private:
    // some other variables
}
```

In a separate part of the code base, how would I cast a `void*` to a `ChildChildClass` instance to a `BaseClass*` such that I can call `getObjectType()` to determine which type of object it points to. I'm currently doing this:

(`someOtherMethod()` returns a `void*` to a `ChildChildClass`)

```
void* initialPointer = someOtherMethod();
BaseClass* basePointer = static_cast<BaseClass>(initialPointer);
if (basePointer->getObjectType() == OBJECT_TYPE::TYPE_3) {
    ChildChildClass* childChildPointer = static_cast<ChildChildClass*>(basePointer);
}
```

I think I may be misunderstanding casting pointers when using inheritance, as I'm getting nonsense values for the returned `objectType` so any advice or info would be appreciated!

Comment: Why are you using `void*` and not `BaseClass *`? Note it is undefined behaviour to cast a `void*` pointer to anything else but the *exact* original type it was obtained from. So `(BaseClass*)(void*)childClassInstance` is UB.  And where's multiple inheritance?

Comment: assuming that you really called 'init()' before converting it to void*. Otherwise m_objType is not initialized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll ignore the numerous issues with such a design and just assume that you have a *very* good reason (i.e. can't change the design) for wanting to do what you're asking for. If you know that `someOtherMethod()` returns a `void*` that points to a `ChildChildClass` object, then you can first `static_cast` that `void*` to a `ChildChildClass*` and then either perform an explicit upcast to a `BaseClass*` or just use that `ChildChildClass*` as a `BaseClass*` since it can implicitly be converted anyways (there should be no need to perform an upcast just for the purpose of calling the method since `ChildChildClass` publicly derives from `BaseClass`):

```
ChildChildClass* initialPointer = static_cast<ChildChildClass*>(someOtherMethod());
BaseClass* basePointer = static_cast<BaseClass*>(initialPointer);
```

However, based on your code above, I am led to believe that you don't actually know that `someOtherMethod()` returns a pointer to a `ChildChildClass` object. Otherwise, why would you have to check whether it does before casting to `ChildChildClass*`? If you don't know the concrete type of object that the `void*` returned by `someOtherMethod()` points to, then there is no way to perform the cast you want to perform here (because there is know way of knowing what should actually be cast into what). One solution would be to change `someOtherMethod()` to always return a `BaseClass*` or at least a `void*` that you know for sure always points to a `BaseClass` object…

Comment: Thanks so much for that! Unfortunately, I think I'm stuck with the `void*` as its coming from an external dependency (I'm trying to process Box2D collisions using callbacks, the physics body class `b2Body` has a `void*` variable which is used to store data about the game objects that are colliding, in this case, pointers to my classes, there are a few different types of object that could collide).
This is really making me think about restructuring things, starting to think there must be a simpler way! So thank you for the information on pointers and for setting me on the right track! :)

Comment: Yes, when interacting with APIs, you sometimes have to pass around `void*` pointers. In this case, make sure that you always know precisely what type that `void*` points to. Then you can always `static_cast` it back to what it was before you converted it to `void*`. You cannot convert back from `void*` and perform an up- or downcast at once because the up- or downcast may involve some pointer adjustments (e.g. when multiple inheritance is involved) that you would miss if you went straight from `void*` to the target type without going over the original pointer type.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`reinterpret_cast<>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast) for casting from a `void*` :

```
 BaseClass* basePointer = reinterpret_cast<BaseClass*>(initialPointer);
```

But be extremely careful ! This is UB if the `initialPointer` would not point to an object of the correct type !

***Additional recommendation:***

For the down-casting, a safer approach would be to use [`dynamic_cast<>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast):

```
ChildChildClass* childChildPointer = dynamic_cast<ChildChildClass*>(basePointer);
if (! childChildPointer) 
    cout << "Something wrong happened !" <<endl;
```

Comment: I think there should be no need for `reinterpret_cast` here, `static_cast` should be perfectly sufficient to cast `void*` to another object pointer type!?

Comment: @MichaelKenzel yes, but reinterpret_cast would have the advantage to highlight that something risky is going on there.  I edited and reformulated "need to" into "should", to take your point into consideration.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using `dynamic_cast`.

```
// This is risky but I assume you know what you are doing.
// BTW, you are using static_cast<BaseClass>. That is not correct.
BaseClass* basePointer = static_cast<BaseClass*>(initialPointer);

// Now use dynamic_cast.
ChildChildClass* childChildPointer = dynamic_cast<ChildChildClass*>(basePointer);

if ( childChildPointer != nullptr)
{
   // Use childChildPointer.
}
else
{
   // Do something different.
}
```

It will be better if `someOtherMethod` can be modified to return a `BaseClass*`.

```
BaseClass* basePointer = someOtherMethod();
```

Then, rest of the code is unlikely to be a problem.

Comment: @KamilCuk, I'm going to guess that my first version had a copy&paste error - `static_cast<BaseClass>(initialPointer)` instead of the correct one.